# How can I use a local repository for Jupyter-lab extensions?

Tags: npm, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install jupyter lab extensions in my environment but my employer has firewalls that prevent me from using the standard repo's available on the internet.  We maintain our own local repo I was able to change npm to look at this repository that is how I was able to install jupyter lab extensions but jupyter labextensions doesnt appear to use the npmrc for its source.  This leads to me trying `jupyter labextension update --all` and it just sitting till it times out

Is there a config file or setting I can set to override the default source for jupyter lab extensions?